# Simplyfing a particular boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm having a lot of trouble with two problems the first is:

```
1) (y*w) + y + w



 What I tried here is applying the distributive law as follows

(y*w) + (y+w)
((y+w) + y) * ((y+w) + w)
((y*w) + y) * ((y*w) + w)
```

then applying the absorption law and getting y*w but the answer is y + w, so I'm unsure how to get it using the laws of Boolean algebra.

2) The second problem I am having issues with is

```
Prove that if x*y = x then ~x*~y = ~y
```

What I tried was negating both sides of the first expression and plugging into the second but that isn't allowed in Boolean algebra it seems.

Comment: 1) Please ask only one question per post. 2) What does "simplify" mean here?

Answer (score 1):

I will use $\land$ instead of `*` and $\lor$ instead of `+`.

**a)** You could  simplify it as following:

$ \ \ \ (y\land w) \lor y \lor w = (y\land w) \lor (y \land T) \lor w = y\land(w \lor T) \lor w = (y \land T) \lor w = y \lor w$

**b)** and prove it as following:

Since $x \land y = x$ we have $\lnot x \lor \lnot y = \lnot x$ by De Morgan's law. By substituting $\lnot x$ in the given equality we have
 
$$\lnot x \land \lnot y = (\lnot x \lor \lnot y) \land\lnot y = (\lnot x\land \lnot y) \lor (\lnot y \land \lnot y) = (\lnot x\land \lnot y) \lor \lnot y = $$
$$=(\lnot x \lor T)\land \lnot y = T \land \lnot y = \lnot y$$

---

Recall that for any boolean $x$ and $y$ the following identities always hold

- $x \lor T = T$
- $x \land T = x$
- $x \land x = x$
- $x \lor x = x$
- $\lnot(x \land y) = \lnot x \lor \lnot y \text{ (De Morgan's law)}$
- $\lnot(x \lor y) = \lnot x \land \lnot y \text{ (De Morgan's law)}$

Answer (score 1):

The first question wants you to simplify a condition of the following sort:

> I am looking for a job which is either *interesting*, or *pays well*, or is *both interesting and pays well*.

You can see that the last option is not really needed.

For the second question, note that

- $x \land y = x$ is the same as $x \Rightarrow y$ ("$x$ implies $y$"), and
- $\lnot x \land \lnot y = \lnot y$ is the same as $\lnot y \Rightarrow \lnot x$, which is the contrapositive of the first statement.

Answer (score 0):

After you got here: ((y+w) + y) * ((y+w) + w)  this is associative.

```
(y*w) + y + w
((y+y) * (y+w)) + w
(y * (y+w)) + w
(w + y) * ((w + y) + w)
(w + y) * (w + y)
w + y
```

Start with a truth table

```
y    w    y*w  (y*w) + y + w
0    0    0    0
0    1    1    0
1    0    1    0
1    1    1    1
```

The equivalency:

```
x * y = x
0   ?   0
1   ?   1
y = 0
```

expansion of x * 0 = x

```
~x * ~y = ~y
0    ~0   ~0
1    ~0   ~0
```

expansion of x * 1 = 1